# Hide HTML tags from data which is rendering from DataBase Angular 6

Tags: angular

I'm getting data in a array from Database through WebAPI. The problem is my text displays like `<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>`, I don't want to display HTML tags, I just want to display the text "Lorem Ipsum". Please provide some solution according to my code. Thanks

HTML
`<p>{{result.CaseSummary}}</p>`

TS
`objResults = [];
this.objResults = this.searchByRecentService.objSearchedResults;`

Comment: Angular isn't made to request HTML from the back-end. If you wish to do so, you can, but it's highly advised you instead use another framework.

Comment: If you really want to use angular for that - try to use `[innerHTML]` option and check that you really get `<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>` and not `&lt;p&gt;Lorem Ipsum&lt;/p&gt;` or something similar.

Comment: @MichalS Thanks. It wokrs!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use external HTML in the Angular app is to use DomSanitizer.

step 1: create a pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

/**
 * Generated class for the SafeHtmlPipe pipe.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe for more info on Angular Pipes.
 */
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}
```

step 2: 
change the `<p>{{result.CaseSummary}}</p>` to

```
<div [innerHTML]="result?.CaseSummary | safeHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so there is  direct way to strip HTML tags from string, you can use Pipe, make a "Pipe":

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'stripHtmlTags'
})

export class StripHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): any {
     return value.replace(/<.*?>/g, ''); // replace tags
    }
}
```

then add "StripHtmlPipe" to your module "declarations", after these steps you can use this pipe in your HTML:

```
<p>{{result.CaseSummary  | stripHtmlTags}}</p>
```